# Which Protocol is suitable if I want a validated person to authenticate the block?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain

I want to create a system in which Every user will have some specific authorities. Like Examination will validate the block containnig Student Marks. Finance should have authority to add block containing Student Fee etc.. For such scenarios which protocol should I go with ? Once the block is added, it should be viewable to all other stakeholders.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing smth similar to OpenLeppelin [Roles](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/access) library. In `roles` directory you can find usage of this library.